# How to reference javascript URL query string with html span tag

Tags: javascript, html, url, get, ref

I have some Javascript that I want to use to reference parts of a URL. I'm trying to insert the query string onto a page using HTML but i'm not sure how. Here is the javascript code:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const ref = urlParams.get('ref')
span = document.getElementById('refName');
txt = document.createTextNode(ref);
span.appendChild(txt);
```

```html
<span id = 'refName'></span>
```

I want to be able to display parts of the URL using HTML. Thanks!

Comment: That should work. Are you getting errors? Whats the problem?